# CSS help for blogger comments widget

Tags: html, css, comments, blogger

I've changed the CSS for the font on my Blogger comments widget, but it's still stuck on Arial for my pages. I've made sure to install the respective Google API font in my template, but it only seems to apply for the comments on my regular posts. This is how my regular post comments look like: http://thereadinggrotto.blogspot.sg/2014/06/first-post.html?showComment=1403768355383#c2121347278617355835

This is how the comments look on my pages: http://thereadinggrotto.blogspot.sg/p/about-mermaid.html?showComment=1403769230075

Here's the CSS for the comments in my blog template:

```
/* =============================
Comment
============================= */
.comments .comments-content {
  font:normal 13px Cabin, sans-serif;
  text-align:left;
  line-height:1.4em;
  margin-bottom:16px;
  color:#305e58;
}
.comments .comments-content .user {
  font:Cabin, sans-serif;
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#305e58;
}
.comments .comments-content .datetime {
  margin-left:10px;
  font:normal 11px Cabin, sans-serif;
  color:#305e58;
}
.comment-replies{
  background:#d3ebe1;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #d3ebe1;
  border-radius:3px;
}
.comments .comment .comment-actions a {
  background:#edf7f2;
  color:#8ba69b;
  padding:2px 5px;
  margin-right:10px;
  font:10px Cabin, sans-serif;
  border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  transition:.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition:.2s linear;
}
.comments .comment .comment-actions a:hover {
  background:#d6f1ec;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition:.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition:.2s linear;
}
.comments .avatar-image-container {
  border-radius:3px;
}  
.comments .thread-toggle a {
  color:#8ba69b;
}
.comments .thread-toggle a:hover {
  padding-left:10px;
  color:#305e58;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.comments .thread-toggle a:hover, .comments .thread-toggle a {
  transition:.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition:.2s linear;
}
#comments h4 {
  margin:1em 0;
  line-height:1.4em;
  letter-spacing:0em;
  color:#305e58;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font:normal 20px Yanone Kaffeesatz;
}
#comments-block {
  margin:1em 0 1.5em;
  line-height:1.6em;
}
#comments-block .comment-author {
  margin:.5em 0;
}
#comments-block .comment-body {
  margin:.25em 0 0;
}
#comments-block .comment-footer {
  margin:-.25em 0 2em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:.1em;
}
#comments-block .comment-body p {
  margin:0 0 .75em;
}
.deleted-comment {
  font-style:italic;
  color:#8ba69b;
}
```

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It looks fine for me. Cabin font has been applied for people comments.

Comment: I just updated my question, sorry! It's the font that's not working for the comments on my pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add font family for comments-block like below.

```
 #comments-block {
 margin:1em 0 1.5em;
 line-height:1.6em;
 font:normal 13px Cabin, sans-serif;
 }
```

If this won't work then apply all the classes under comments-block like below.

```
 #comments-block .comment-author {
  margin:.5em 0;
  font:normal 13px Cabin, sans-serif; 
 }
 #comments-block .comment-body {
  margin:.25em 0 0;
  font:normal 13px Cabin, sans-serif;
 }
 #comments-block .comment-footer {
 margin:-.25em 0 2em;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing:.1em;
 font:normal 13px Cabin, sans-serif;
}
#comments-block .comment-body p {
 margin:0 0 .75em;
 font:normal 13px Cabin, sans-serif;
}
```